# How to use C# Stream Reader to save a completion of a process?

Tags: c#, file, process, streamreader

I have a program which uses a CMD program to execute various arguements.

The arguements that would work in a normal CMD would be C:\temp\bin\fls.exe -m C: -r C:\temp\image.dd > C:\temp\bin\ntfs.bodyfile .

The C# program that I have written only works till  C:\temp\bin\fls.exe -m C: -r C:\temp\image.dd but does not execute the > C:\temp\bin\ntfs.bodyfile which means save the process into the ntfs.bodyfile.

I have read many other websites and they all point to the problem of my program missing a streamreader to save the completion of the process into a file. So can someone please advise on my program to allow the process to be saved into a file? Thanks!

One such similar website that has a same problem would be: [StreamReader to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521725/streamreader-to-file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Process process = new Process();
       process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\temp\\bin\\fls.exe";
       process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-m C: -r C:\\temp\\image.dd > 
       C:\\temp\\bin\\ntfs.bodyfile";
       process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
       process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
       process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
       process.Start();

       System.IO.StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
       string sRes = reader.ReadToEnd();
       Console.WriteLine(sRes);
       reader.Close();  
   }   
 }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what is your circumstance but it's better doing `using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput){...}` instead of your open close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are all very varied but I finally found the answer to the question.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
 class Program
 {
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Process process = new Process();
       process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\temp\\bin\\fls.exe";
       process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-m C: -r C:\\temp\\image.dd";
       process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
       process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
       process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
       process.Start();

       System.IO.StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
       string sRes = reader.ReadToEnd();
       StreamWriter SW;
       SW = File.CreateText("C:\\temp\\ntfs.bodyfile");
       SW.WriteLine(sRes);
       SW.Close();
       Console.WriteLine("File Created SucacessFully");
       reader.Close();  
   }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the shell which performs the redirection, so that part of your arguments list is being handed straight to fls. You should remove it.

You *can* read directly from standard out and error, and save the data that way - or you could call cmd and give it all the arguments to make it redirect the output.

Note that if you *do* use the standard output and standard error, you should probably be reading one of them from a different thread - or don't redirect it. Currently if the process writes a lot of data to standard error, you're not reading it and it will eventually run out of buffer space and block.

Answer (score 1):

**In your example, the output of `fls.exe` should appear in `ntfs.bodyfile` since you're redirecting the output of `fls.exe` to that file.**

Because you are redirecting the output of `fls.exe` to that file, `sRes` should stay empty.

There are a few issues. Firstly, you do not wait for the process to exit. If the above program is your complete program, this should not be an issue. However, if you are going to read the output of `ntfs.bodyfile`, you should wait for the process to exit. Try the following:

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\temp\\bin\\fls.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-m C: -r C:\\temp\\image.dd > C:\\temp\\bin\\ntfs.bodyfile";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.Start();

    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        string sRes = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(sRes);
        reader.Close();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

This will both ensure that the `Process` is cleaned up, you wait for `fls.exe` to complete and you correctly close the `StreamReader`.

Now concerning the ouput. There are two options. If you want the output to appear in `ntfs.bodyfile`, you should be set. However, if you want the output to appear in `sRes`, you should remove the `> C:\\temp\\bin\\ntfs.bodyfile` from the arguments.